# Recursive `rowid` in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, rowid

I have a sqlite table `t` with two columns: a `ROWID` primary key column called `id` and a column `c` which is a foreign key to `t` itself:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t (     
     id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
     c INT NOT NULL,
     FOREIGN KEY (c) REFERENCES t(id));
```

Inserts are straightforward as long as `c` refers to a row already inserted, but I'm not sure how to insert a row whose `c` refers to that row itself. Is this possible in sqlite?

I know that SQLite is able to return the last inserted row id, so I could hack something together like:

1. transaction begin
2. insert a preliminary row with `c` pointing to a dummy value
3. retrieve the last inserted row id
4. upgrade the preliminary row to its final form, now with the correct value for `c`
5. commit transaction

Is this the right approach?

Comment: Your approach is fine. But why *... with c pointing to a dummy value*? You can set it to `null`.

Comment: I would have to make `c` nullable for just this reason, wouldn't I?

Comment: Please read the info on the sqlite tag you used and make a corresponding MRE. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sqlite/info

Comment: If it is not nullable how would you insert the 1st row? You would have to hardcode it to 1 (like the first id). And after that you will have to be sure that the *dummy* value exists in the table. Is this possible? If yes then do it.

Comment: You should read https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_deferred